# Is there anything wrong with changing the default compiler in Xcode 4.2 to GCC 4.2?

Tags: iphone, gcc, compiler-construction, compatibility

I am having some issues in my app since the advent of iOS 5, and I am trying to figure out what in the world is going on. One of the noticeable differences in the development environment is the switch to the Apple LLVM 3.0 as the default compiler (correct me if I am wrong), and so I'm thinking that if I switch that back to LLVM GCC 4.2, that it may help.

Will that open up any other compatibility issues? What are the ramifications of switching compiler versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean clang (which apple calls "apple compiler suite 3" or some such) vs llvm-gcc. Straight gcc (both backend and frontend) is not an option with Xcode 4.2

I still use llvm-gcc as opposed to clang. I have code (notably with a lot of C++) that still produces different results (= core dumps) with clang. Clang's gotten a lot better but stil seems to have issues, particularly with C++.

On the other hand llvm-gcc has been very solid with 4.2 (which wasn't the case with prior to 4.2).

I'm not sure if ARC works with llvm-gcc. I kinda thought that was clang-only thing ... but I don't use it, so I'm not sure.